# How to use Twitter API Collections?

Tags: java, twitter

Before I used twitter4j, but it seems that doesnt implement the Twitter API Collections.
I created a collection manually with TweetDeck, I want to get this collection with a java code. I know url use for that is :
 https://api.twitter.com/1.1/collections/list.json?screen_name=...&user_id=...
But I don't know how to get the list of collections programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interesting in, I finally found.
 With Twitter4j:

```
        public JSONObject GetListCollections(String user_id) throws TwitterException, IOException, JSONException {
            // GET Collection list, https://api.twitter.com/1.1/collections/list.json?user_id= (ou screen_name=)
            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();    
            cb.setHttpProxyHost(Constant.ProxyHost);
            cb.setHttpProxyPort(Constant.ProxyPort);
            cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(Constant.consumerkey);
            cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constant.consumerSecret);
            cb.setOAuthAccessToken(Constant.accessToken);
            cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(Constant.accessTokenSecret); 
            Configuration conf = cb.build();
            HttpClient HC = HttpClientFactory.getInstance(conf.getHttpClientConfiguration());
            HttpParameter[] HPs = {new HttpParameter("user_id",user_id)};
            Authorization A = new OAuthAuthorization(conf);
            HttpResponseListener HRL = new HttpResponseListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void httpResponseReceived(HttpResponseEvent event) {
                        System.out.println(event.isAuthenticated()+"\n"+event.getRequest()+"\n"+event.getResponse());               
                    }           
            };
            HttpResponse HR = HC.get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/collections/list.json",HPs, A, HRL);
            System.out.println("HR.getStatusCode = "+HR.getStatusCode());
            return HR.asJSONObject();
      }
```